# Determining the resistor value to dissipate energy in inductive and capacitive components in the circuit

Tags: filter

I am trying to model the following low-loss LC circuit, but I need to add a resistive load to dissipate the energy that accumulates in the inductive and capacitive components. I am not sure I fully understand this, so some feedback as to whether the following is correct would be much appreciated.

[image: filter circuit]

Basically I would add a resistor in parallel with C3 and C4. To calculate the value of the resistor, I first got the capacitive equivalent of C1, C2, C3 and C4 ie 1/c(eq) = 1/C1 + 1/C2 + 1/(C3+C4). The value was 57.49nF.

For the total inductance of the transformer, L1 + L2 + -2M, where M is sqrt(L1*L2). In the above the results are 0.00204 and -0.01996, but a negative value doesn't seem to make sense so I would discard it.

Then I calculated total impedance:
50Hz from the power supply is 314.16 rad/s (w)
So, Z(Total) is R + X(L) + X(C) = R + j(wL - 1/(wC)) = 100K + j(0.06408864 + 0.00001806105) = 100K + j0.0641067

So the current in the circuit is: I = V(s)/Z(total)
which is 240/(100K+j0.0641067) = 0.0024-0.00000000153j

I: jwL = j0.00001806105
C: j(1/wC) = 0.06408864

from V=IZ

V(inductive): 0.00000004334-2.76334*10^(-14)
V(capacitive): 0.00015381273 - 9.80556* 10^(-11)

Total V(Z) is: 0.00015386 - 9.808322*10^(-11)

Would you then insert a resistor to the value of 0.00015386/0.0024 = 0.0641083, with V and I real values taken from above?

Comment: What's the purpose of the added resistor(s)? Without knowing what you want to achieve, it's not possible to comment on the values you come up with.

Comment: I'm trying to more accurately model the frequency response of the circuit, to take into account the energy that accumulates in the inductive and capacitive components. So the resistive load would dissipate that energy.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's a non-answer, you've just re-ordered things you've already said in the OP. You do not need to 'take account of' energy stored in Ls and Cs. If your filter is loaded with a load, then model the load. Model the resistive and core loss of the Ls with a series R if you want a more accurate representation for them. You can generally ignore capacitive losses, unless the capacitor has a built-in discharge resistor. If your filter is not loaded with a load, then you'll simulate what you'd get in real life, a bouncy response. Is that a problem?

Comment: I'm doing an assignment and this is exactly what we have been asked to do (what I asked). We don't have the details of the load beyond that it is attached to a rectifier, which is in turn attached to a high frequency inverter, which is in turn attached to a stepdown transformer. "When modelling the frequency response, consider including a resistive load to dissipate energy that accumulates in the indutive and capacitive components". So they want us to include both. I'm just not surre if what I did was correct.

Comment: The part of the paragraph before that quite I couldn't fit in, but it is: "The partial circuit being analysed is a low loss LC network and would be expected to display resonance. In practice, there will be power dissipating elements elsewhere in the device. When modelling the frequency response consider including a resistive load to dissipate energy that accumulates in the inductive and capacitive components"

Comment: It sounds like then you need to model a load, external to this filter. It's a 240v supply. Let's say you have 1 amp of filament light load ( easiest to model). Put 240 ohms (1 amp at 240v) across the output, and see how this changes the frequency response of the filter. You might also want to model the loss in the K1 component. Then load the output with a rectifier/capacitor load, and put a resistor across that to draw current. Modelling the series resistance of the rectifier diodes might be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of your assignment, what you need to do is to make **and state** some assumptions, and then model what you have assumed.

For instance, you could make the following assumptions - zero impedance mains, lossless components, open circuit filter. This would result in a very bouncy response, as the only dissipative element is R1, which is there just to discharge the capacitors when the circuit is disconnected.

Or you assume the same conditions, but with a 1 amp lamp load of 240 ohms loading the output, or 5 amps.

Or you could model it with a perfect rectifier/capacitor load drawing an average of 1 amp, or 10mA, or 10A.

Or you could model a lossy K1 (look at some commercial filters, some will tell you what their loss is) with some resistance in series with it.

Or with the rectifier load, model some intrinsic series diode resistance, and some electrolytic capacitor ESR, they will all absorb energy and tame the response, and perhaps a sniff of mains impedance, a fraction of an ohm.

Or you could do all of those, and compare and contrast the frequency responses. That will get you the most bonus marks, and the most understanding.

Comment: thank you, I will look into those. I don't really know anything about rectifiers, but I might have a look at what they typically draw.

Comment: I've been trying to find the power absorbed by a typical rectifier, and I am not sure. Does anyone have any idea? I would prefer to build a realistic model. Failing that I guess it is a light bulb. It takes 50KHz and outputs 100KHz.